# windows 10 not bootable after ubuntu 16

Tags: boot, windows, uefi, uninstall

I  installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along side  Windows 10. Now when when I boot the sysytem, only Ubuntu is bootable. There appears a Windows option but it fails to boot when selected. It shows the following error message.

```
/EndEntire
filepath:/ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(2,1f)/sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,200800,32000,23780ea1aa1de311,2,2)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire
error: cannot load image.
```

I badly want to get my Windows back.Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Question: did you install Ubuntu as with EFI? Both Windows and Ubuntu -must- use the same method. Either both with or both without EFI (and since Windows enforces it ...)

Comment: i installed Ubuntu from a bootable pendrive. The pendrive has files named bootx64.efi.hence, i believe it's efi.

Comment: You may be running into [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464) If so, disabling Secure Boot or installing my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) may work around the problem.

Comment: Wow..That worked. I disabled secure boot and now Windows is booting. Thank you so much..   Is there any problem in disabling the secure boot?